# Most memory efficient way to re format a JSON array in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have a JSON array similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "title": "This is a title",
    "year": 2013,
    "images": {
      "image": "http://........jpg",
    },
    "ratings": {
      "thumbsup": 1053,
      "thumbsdown": 256
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title",
    "year": 2013,
    "images": {
      "image": "http://........jpg",
    },
    "ratings": {
      "thumbsup": 1053,
      "thumbsdown": 256
    }
  }
]
```

And the required output is a JSON array like this:

```
[
      {
        "title": "This is a title",
        "images": {
          "image": "http://........jpg",
        },
        "ratings": {
          "thumbsup": 1053,
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "This is a title",
        "images": {
          "image": "http://........jpg",
        },
        "ratings": {
          "thumbsup": 1053,
        }
      }
    ]
```

Iv'e been researching and it's suggested that the most efficient way would be to parse it using the Jackson streaming API. This is for use on a PaaS with limited memory, so I wish to keep the memory usage to the bare minimum.

Is the best way to parse the JSON with Jackson Streaming API, and construct a new JSON array at the same time or simply remove the elements somehow?

Comment: Are the rules on which fields to omit dynamic ? Can you elaborate on the use case ?

Comment: Is the absence of "thumbsdown" the memory optimization?

Comment: Deepak - The fields on which need to be removed from each JSON object are the same for each object in the array.

Comment: RC - No, This is an example. Each JSON object will have potentially a lot of elements, and I wish to remove the ones I do not need for bandwidth reasons. I speak of memory optimisations as in I want the most efficient way to do this, not because it itself is a memory optimisation.

Comment: Why don't you just remove them from the class and then add the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) to ignore fields that are not there. would it work for you?

Comment: Saeid - Could I still use the streaming API for this, or would I have to use the binding method?

Comment: Saeid - After much consideration, and the lack of answers here I'm going to use data bindings and use your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similiar with XML once.  You can have the requestor tell you what fields you want to get back, and have it only emit those.  In my case I had no control over the 3rd party axis xml view, but once I had the view, when I asked for things from it if it was already there I could give back just the pieces I was interested in.  As a bonus, if you are marshalling or unmarshalling real java objects from the JSON after getting the json or XML you don't need to build the part of the object graph you don't care about.